# How do I remove a dictionary index from a list on Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, pickle

I am creating a program which stored the High scores of players in an arcade.
The List I am using for this is referred to as PlayerID, as it contains a Unique ID and other information such as their high score in each game. Whenever I try to successfully remove a dictionary from the list of Players, it does not work correctly, deleting multiple profiles.

This is the code I am currently using. Pickle is being used for data storage.

```
with open("playerdata.dat",'rb') as f:
    PlayerID = pickle.load(f)    
while True:
    try:
        SearchID= int(input("Enter the ID of the profile you are removing")) # used to check if a wanted user actually exists in the program
    except ValueError:
        print("You have not provided an integer input, please try again.") #performs type check to ensure a valid input is provided
        continue
    else:
        break    

index= 0
position = -1
for Player in PlayerID:
    if Player['ID'] == SearchID:
        position = index
    else:
        index = index + 1
    try:
        PlayerID.pop(position)
    except IndexError:
        print("The ID provided does not exist.")
print("The user with ID", searchID,", has been deleted")    
with open('playerdata.dat','wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(playerID,f,pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

Also even when an Integer ID is input that does not actually exist on the PlayerID list, it still deletes multiple profiles even though I have the IndexError code in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a simpler way to accomplish this:

```
for index, Player in enumerate(PlayerID):
    if Player['ID'] == SearchID:
        PlayerID.pop(index)
        print("The user with ID", SearchID, ", has been deleted")
        break
else:
    print("The ID provided does not exist.")
```

Comment: Would I need to used the predefined value of Index = 0 or would index be read as its own value?

Comment: No, the `for` loop as written will cause `index` to start at 0.  You don't have to set it yourself.

Comment: I've just noticed with your code, does the "foundID" in the if statement mean to have an "= True" at the end of it?

Comment: No, that's not necessary.  The `if` statement expects a boolean value following it, and `foundID` is a boolean value.  The main block of the `if` statement executes if `foundID` is True, and the `else` block executes if `foundID` is False.

Comment: Apologies, but another error has been raised after this solution. The code only seems to want to delete the dictionary at literally index 0.

Comment: Brionius how could i rectify the issue?

Comment: If you add the statement `print(PlayerID)` after you load the data, and show me what the output is, I might be able to help.

Comment: http://gyazo.com/ea4827f1a9d4928c55aa0832eabbea69 879 is the ID that was at index 0, whenever I attempt to delete the ID at index 1, which has the ID 539 associated with it, it will state it does not exist. Then when I proceed to delete ID 539, when it is located at index 0, it then actually recognises the input and deletes it. http://gyazo.com/fe72930ff7fef940bae03c46243c366b

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `-1` is a valid list index in Python; it would pop the last element in the list.

It is easier to just pop once you meet right id. Also, you can use `enumerate` to count the indices:

```
for index, player in enumerate(players):
    if player['ID'] == search_id:
        players.pop(index)
        # we expect that the ID is truly unique, there is
        # only 1 occurrence of the ID.
        break
```

Now of course one might ask, why don't you use a dictionary of id->player to store the players - then you can do:

```
if search_id in players:
    players.pop(search_id)
```

Comment: I have tried incorporating your first method of doing this, but it does not seem to at all delete the wanted dictionary from the playerdata.dat file

Comment: in that case it might mean that `search_id` is not a match for the ID's in your file; maybe you used `str`s for ids, but now entered an int

Comment: The ID's are random and are generated through the randint() function. The program just seems to refuse to delete the list which contains the ID I want to remove